# Changing the default title size of the titlebar

Tags: android

I implemented my own title in android using this following codes:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_load);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.activity_title);
```

Unfortunately, the output is this:

[image: android]

I want to change the height of the title(left) similar to title(right). Modifying the height of the activity_title.xml wont work! Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use custom layout and integrate that?
R.layout.activity_title-> is your activity title
activity_load-> main screen..

in activity_load.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/activity_title" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" >
      // use your load screen here..
   </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

 In code:
 this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // no need of title.
```

as you created custom layout where you can apply.If you don't want for some screens just make as include header gone in programatically.

Comment: Most of my activities implement ListActivity so how do you use the keyword include in an implemented class like ListActivty?

Comment: i am saying to implement in xml and use it.